# Parse the data incoming from the buffer of Serial.readBytes()

Tags: serial, array

I want to parse the data of the incoming buffer from the serial read bytes, but I don't really know how to get the data out of the array and save it to different variables.

This is my code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

struct buf {
  byte FunctionCode;
  byte Length;
  byte Message;
  byte Checksum;
} data;



void loop() {
  int Length = Serial.available();
  byte Buffer[Length];
  byte IncomingData[Length];
  if (Length >= 0)
  {
    Serial.readBytes(Buffer, Length);
    data.FunctionCode = Buffer[0 - 1];
  }
}
```

Comment: What data? How is it formatted? Look at `strtok()` to do the heavy work for you.

Comment: @Majenko this is the incoming data: |61|191|16|0|61|191|100|23|0|0|0|0|0|0|131|2| (without the "|"), I can't use strtok because I'm not using string, they're just bytes

Comment: A string is just bytes...

Comment: @Majenko Yeah, btw I fixed everything just by using a for loop and some if statements

Comment: @alessandromrc, is it fair to say that you don't control for the format of the data being sent to you?

Comment: @timemagei I just send raw bytes to the Arduino

Comment: That sounds like "yes."  Part of what I'm getting at is you have could use any number of libraries for existing protocols.  Just from your `FunctionCode` mention alone, it's reminding me of MODBUS.

Comment: @timemage haha, It's a MODBUS emulation for real ... If I have to be really honest I'm not a fan of libraries, I prefer learning how to do everything by myself so I can understand how it really works and not by just hearing that by somebody else